# set gridview scrolling disable android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

*I have a Gridview of values in listview.*

**every  listview position contain a textview and gridview.
and every gridview contain a set of items.**

***But,to view all items i have to go through scroll. 
I want to show the full list of items ,without scrolling.***

```
<GridView
                android:id="@+id/grid_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="70dp"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp" 

                >
            </GridView>
```

Comment: Can you post your trial code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two scrollable view as same derivatives. 
**Android** doesn't recommend having a *child scrollable* view when you already have a scrollable view as parent .

Although, if you want to achieve this there are many other ways, I will suggest you better have a linear layout and inflate it dynamically whenever your **listView** items gets in.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off clicks on GridView by setting "**clickable**" attribute to **false**

That will toggle scrolling off too.